# Is mapToDouble() really necessary for summing a List<Double> with Java 8 streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

As far as I can tell, the way to sum a `List<Double>` using Java 8 streams is this:

```
List<Double> vals = . . . ;
double sum = vals.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum();
```

To me, the `mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)` seems kind of crufty - just the sort of boilerplate "ceremony" that lambdas and streams were supposed to dispense with.

Best practices tell us to prefer `List` instances over arrays, and yet for this sort of summing, arrays seem cleaner:

```
double[] vals = . . . ;
double sum = Arrays.stream(vals).sum();
```

Granted, one could do this:

```
List<Double> vals = . . . ;
double sum = vals.stream().reduce(0.0, (i,j) -> i+j);
```

But that `reduce(....)` is so much longer than `sum()`.

I get that this has to do with the way streams need to be retrofitted around the Java's non-object primitives, but still, am I missing something here?  Is there some way to squeeze autoboxing in to make this shorter?  Or is this just the current state of the art?

---

### Update - Answers Digest

Here is a digest of answers below. While I have a summary here, I urge the reader to peruse the answers themselves in full.

@dasblinkenlight explains that some kind of unboxing will always be necessary, due to decisions made further back in the history of Java, specifically in the way generics were implemented and their relationship to the non-object primitives. He notes that it is theoretically possible for the compiler to intuit the unboxing and allow for briefer code, but this has not yet been implemented.

@Holger shows a solution that is very close to the expressiveness I was asking about:

```
double sum = vals.stream().reduce(0.0, Double::sum);
```

I was unaware of the new static `Double.sum()` method.  Added with 1.8, it seems intended for the very purpose I was describing.  I also found `Double.min()` and `Double.max()`.  Going forward, I will definitely use this idiom for such operations on `List<Double>` and similar.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question but a blog post rant in question disguise!

Comment: I would urge you to reconsider.  This was an honest question:  "Is there some way to squeeze autoboxing in to make this shorter?"  Any opinion I expressed served to explain the motivation for the question.  The answers enlightened me on both Java typing and new methods on the primitive wrappers that I did not know about.  They have helped me to write better code.  This was nothing close to a "rant."

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> To me, the `mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)` seems [what] lambdas and streams were supposed to dispense with.

The need to use `mapToDouble` is a consequence of a decision to implement generics via type erasure, essentially closing the door on any possibility of using primitives inside generics. It is that same decision that made it necessary to create the `DoubleStream`, `IntStream`, and `LongStream` family of classes - to provide a stream-based unboxing.

> Is there some way to squeeze autoboxing in to make this shorter? Or is this just the current state of the art?

Unfortunately, not at this time: although it is theoretically possible for the compiler to figure out that `Stream<Double>` can be converted to `DoubleStream` implicitly, in the same way that the primitives are unboxed, this has not been done.

As far as your array-based solution goes, it is the most efficient of the three. However, it is not as flexible as the other two: the one with `mapToDouble` lets you sum any attribute of a custom class, while the last one lets you perform other types of aggregation.

> `reduce(....)` is so much longer than `sum()`

I agree, this approach is worse than `mapToDouble` in terms of readability.

Comment: Argh, I was honestly hoping I had missed something in the APIs but I guess not.  I very much appreciate your placing the explanation in the context of the overall history of Java typing, as well as the thought process around it.  This makes the situation much more understandable as something intrinsic to the language design and not just a missing API call. I think it makes for a useful reference.

Comment: I'm really looking forward to Project Valhalla, http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/discuss/2014-June/003445.html

Answer (score 54):

> Is there some way to squeeze autoboxing in to make this shorter?

Yes, there is. You can simply write:

```
double sum = vals.stream().mapToDouble(d->d).sum();
```

This makes the unboxing implicit but, of course, does not add to efficiency.

Since the `List` *is* boxed, unboxing is unavoidable. An alternative approach would be:

```
double sum = vals.stream().reduce(0.0, Double::sum);
```

It does not do a `mapToDouble` but still allows reading the code as “… sum”.

Comment: Nice - I very much like the second one - thanks!  I was unaware of the new `sum()` method on `Double`.

Answer (score 7):

Here is another way to do it. If you just need a sum, average, min, max etc. on a list of `Double`, `Integer` or `Long`, you can use one of the available `Collectors`, e.g.:

```
List<Double> doubles = Arrays.asList(3.14, 5.15, 4.12, 6.);
System.out.println(
        doubles.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.summingDouble(d -> d))
);
```

would print **18.41**

Note, the method name is **summingDouble**, there is another method called **summarizingDouble**, which returns `DoubleSummaryStatistics`, containing all the basic math operations results.

Comment: is there any way to assign the values of the average, min, max and sum all at same time while doing just one stream? (im sorry, im not good with lambdas)

Comment: @jpganz18 that’s actually in the answer already. Use `summarizingDouble` when you want average, min, max and sum in one go.