# Cleaner map reduce with Java 8 and a HashMap

Tags: java, java-8, reduce, java-stream

Right now I have a HashMap I'm trying to reduce to a total. Here's the current code:

```
HashMap map = new HashMap<String, Long>();
map.put("ex1", 757L);
map.put("ex2", 77L);

map.values()
   .stream()
   .reduce(0L, (a, b) -> a + b);
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? I'd like to use the sum method.

Comment: Similarly to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24421140/2711488), just replace `double` with `int`, resp. `Double` with `Integer`…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `mapToLong` to get a `LongStream` then call `sum()`

```
long sum = map.values().stream().mapToLong(i -> i).sum();
```