# How to total a list of numbers in FreeMarker

Tags: java, freemarker

I've been going through the [documentation for FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui.html) and I can't find any examples of how to sum up a list of values in a list.

So let's say I have the following class, how do I add a line at the end to include the totals of values:

```
public class MyObject
{
    List<long> values
}
```

I can then view the individual items [as explained in the list directive](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_quickstart_template.html#autoid_4).

```
<#list MyObject.values as value>
  ${value}
</#list>
```

I can even find the [documentation on how to do arithmetic on the individual values](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_arit) but how can I then add a new line to show the total of all the values? In other words I can't find any documentation on how to sum a list of numbers...

And also can you please include the link to the page in the documentation that explains how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Could you just add a `getSum()` method to `MyObject`? Also, a `List` can't hold primitive types. It must using the wrapping class. ie `List<Long>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Java 8, there are built-in functions for finding the sum of a `List<Long>`. If you convert the `List` to a `Stream` to a `LongStream`, you can use [`.sum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#sum--):

```
${MyObject.values.stream().mapToLong(Long::longValue).sum()}
```

You can see this at work in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421140/is-maptodouble-really-necessary-for-summing-a-listdouble-with-java-8-streams) for example.

Answer (score 2):

This is a custom function to do it. I just took the function to average a list of numbers and changed it slightly.

```
<#function mysum nums...>
  <#local sum = 0>
  <#list nums as num>
    <#local sum += num>
  </#list>
  <#if nums?size != 0>
    <#return sum>
  </#if>
</#function>
${mysum(10, 20)}
30
```

This is where I got the original function for averaging a list:
http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_function.html (see Example 2)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have to admit I'm surprised there's no built-in summation function on a list... I guess there's a reason...

Comment: I'm glad the function works for you. I can't tell you what the designers of the language were thinking, but even in R (a statistics and math focused language) you can't use `sum` on a list. Of course, the data types are different in R anyway.

Comment: It's a template language, moreover one that was originally used for MVC Views. You aren't supposed to do calculations in such templates.

Comment: As of the function, I'm not sure if people want to get `null`/missing instead of 0 if the list is empty, so maybe the last if could be removed. Also note that you can use `<#local sum += num>` (which is somewhat shorter).

Comment: @ddekany Well ok lol, that's kind of a trivial and irrelevant criticism but I suppose that's true. I'm just giving an example of how to make a sum of a list by changing the documentation's list average function example though... if you're one of the maintainers of the language and you feel the function should be improved wouldn't it make more sense for you to improve it in your documentation (as mentioned in the solution, that's where I forked it) rather than in a random fork of it on StackOverflow?

Comment: Sure, the `+=` will be fixed in the docs. But the `#if` is not needed in your case as the sum of 0 items is meaningful, while the average of them (from the manual) isn't.