# It is possible to define the return type of a lambda expression?

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have the following code

```
Random rnd = new Random();
rnd.ints().limit(100)
          .filter(i-> i > 0)
          .map(Math::sqrt)
          .forEach(System.out::println)
```

Which generates the following compile error:

```
Streams.java:12: error: incompatible types: bad return type in method reference
                .map(Math::sqrt)
                     ^
    double cannot be converted to int
```

If I use instead

```
.mapToDouble(Math::sqrt)
```

It works. The problem is that the compiler cannot infer the return type of the lambda expression used in map. Is there a way to specify it explicitly? I personally find the `mapToxxx` set of functions clumsy.

Comment: Probably related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421140/is-maptodouble-really-necessary-for-summing-a-listdouble-with-java-8-streams

Comment: Ouch. Type erasure strikes again...

Comment: Yeap, you both right, and that was my fear.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Nope, this has absolutely nothing to do with erasure.  This is only about the OP mis-reading the documentation.

Comment: @BrianGoetz you are right. Lazy of me! I thought that `IntStream` was a subclass of `Stream`, which is not the case (it is a subclass of `BaseStream`), and therefore the `map` method's signature is different, as you pointed out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with "declaring the return type of your lambda."  You're just specifying an invalid argument to `map()`, and the compiler is telling you so.

The `map` method in `IntStream` takes an `IntUnaryOperator` (a function from `int` to `int`).  There is no method `Math.sqrt` that can be converted to this signature.

Comment: You are right @brian-goetz, I was just wondering why the mapToxxx are needed if the map function in Stream is defined as: `<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)` and said to "Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream"

Comment: The `map()` function in `Stream` is defined that way, because `Stream` is a stream of object references.  But `IntStream` is a stream of `int`.  If we defined `Instream.map()` like `Stream.map()`, the result would _always be boxed_.  Which defeats the purpose of using `IntStream`.